# How to convert RSK token balance to a Javascript number?

Tags: javascript, web3js, rsk

I want to get the balance (number of tokens) from the token smart contract.

I'm using web3.js to interact with the contract, and am able to get a return value.
However, with this value, if I do `.toString()`, I see that it has the correct value.
However, if I do `.toNumber()`, it gives me an error:
`Error: Number can only safely store up to 53 bits`

Why does this happen? And how can I get the balance of a particular account from a smart contract, **as  a number** (not a string)?

Answer (score 3):

Smart contracts can support extremely large numbers (up to `uint256` in Solidity). However the built in `Number` type of Javascript cannot represent numbers that large, and thus in `web3.js`, any numeric values are wrapped in `BN` (Big Number). You can find this class in `web3.utils.BN`.

This is why when you get the error that you are getting for your balance query,
because balances are `uint256`, and typically used to represent `18` decimal places. We can reproduce  this using only web3.js, without

```js
const web3 = require('web3');

// the balance is a `1` with 21 `0`-s after it
// typical token would return this value for an account with 1000 tokens
const balanceBN = new web3.utils.BN('1000000000000000000000');
const balance = balanceBN.toNumber();
```

This throws the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Number can only safely store up to 53 bits
    at assert (/some/path/node_modules/bn.js/lib/bn.js:6:21)
    at BN.toNumber (/some/path/node_modules/bn.js/lib/bn.js:519:7)
```

Therefore, your options are:

- You can use `.toNumber()` if the BN is small enough.
- If the BN is too large, use `.div()` to size it down before calling `.toNumber()`.

Applying the above to your specific question, about getting token balances,
we can do the following:

```js
const balanceBN = contract.methods.balanceOf(myAddress).call();
const decimalsBN = contract.methods.decimals().call();

// when we know that the BN is small engouh to be represented in JS number
const decimals = decimalsBN.toNumber();

// when we know that the BN is too alrge to be represented in JS number

const balance = balanceBN.div(new  web3.utils.BN(10).pow(decimalsBN)).toNumber();
```

- Query the token contract to get the balance and decimals values, both as `BN`
- Convert decimals to a number directly, using `.toNumber()`, since we are expecting this to be small enough
- Divide the balance `BN` by 10 raised to the power of the decimals `BN`, and then call `.toNumber` on it

> NOTE: The resulting value of `balance` will match the number of tokens that is typically show in user interfaces... not the value stored in the smart contract itself.

Answer (score 2):

or use BN from - it extends bytes length and actually is better (xmr / vet also needs more digits) - http://silentmatt.com/biginteger/